# Django app scope questions

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-templates

I am fairly new to Django, having done the tutorial front to back and back to front with a website I am creating myself.

However, there are - currently - about two question that stop me from progressing. As background: I'm an enterprise java developer so I'm familiar with database design, foreign keys and the importance of entity/model scoping. Also, I created websites with php and mysql and was therefore familiar with including header/footers/menus etc. Switching to Django is difficult partially because of this, since Django uses template inheritance to 'include' pages, which is quite a bit different from including each footer/header/menu in each page.

For these questions, imagine someone who likes to recreate the youtube website with Django (just hypothetical! - who would want to do this anyway?)

1. How would one define the app scope? I read on multiple sources (among which the django website) that an app should be really small, in our example perhaps: comment app, video upload app, suggested videos app etc. However - in my view - comments should have a foreign key to a video and a foreign key to a user. If one would design a comment app, how would one solve those foreign key contraints/dependencies since they would need to point to a different app? Or perhaps, how SHOULD one scope the apps?
2. Related to question 1, about templates... Designing views and templates for a single app is not really a problem (yet). However how does one bring multiple apps together. For example, one could create a 'home' app that holds the menu, header, footer, login and such. But that means that other apps - like comments - need to extend that view creating yet another dependency to the home app. How would one do this in django?

Note that I'm not looking for full code - although code snippets might help explain the concepts - but these questions are more theoretical.

Comment: Good to know that we don't have to worry about foreign keys across apps.  So to the question: how should we scope apps?

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of over-thinking this. An app is really just a convenient grouping of code. There's nothing that stops apps having a foreign key to a model in another app: indeed, that's more or less required, especially in the case of linking to users since they are provided by the contrib.auth app.

As regards templates, this isn't specifically to do with apps, but with any template that needs to gather data from multiple places. The usual way to do this is by using custom template tags - probably [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) - to query and render the data.